# Magento collection grouping and limiting by value range

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, magento

I am sure this can be solved with some clever mysql expression or zend joins, but I just dont have enough knowledge here to solve, hopefully someone in the SO community can.

Say I have a collection of products in Magento and they are ordered by category position.

I only want to retrieve 2 products from the collection, those with the highest category position.

The following should illustrate:

```
Category:
    Product A (position 3);
    Product B (position 1);
    Product C (position 0);
    Product D (position 2);
```

In this collection, I only want to retrieve Product C and B since these are the two highest positions.

Another illustration:

```
Category:
    Product A (position 1);
    Product B (position 3);
    Product C (position 0);
    Product D (position 2);
```

In this collection, I only want to retrieve Product C and A.

How can this be done in a single collection load. For example I do not want to load the collection and then iterate over and manually sort etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$coll = $_category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position','ASC');
$coll->getSelect()->limit(2);
$coll->load();
```

Afterwards you can iterate over your collection:

```
foreach ($coll as $product) {
   // Do sth. with $product
}
```